# Call a function in other version of Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle, python-3.4

It's possible to call a function from other .py file. But can we force Python to do it with another version?

**Problem:**
My Python version is 3.4.

I need to connect to an Oracle 10g database. Unfortunately there is no version of cx_Oracle which can connect Python 3.4 with 10g (there is a version, but only for Oracle 11g and above). I must therefore use Python 2.7 so I can use a version of cx_Oracle, which supports 10g. In this configuration my code which was running on 3.4 needs various adaptations, and it's thousands of lines.

**Solution:**

1. All of my current code will be running still on 3.4
2. When I need to I connect to the database with a function in other .py file, but it has to be run on 2.7

How can I run Python 2.7 within 3.4?

Comment: What OS are you using? If it's Windows, can you switch to ODBC?

Comment: It is Windows. Unfortunately, cant change it. If i would, I think that most simple would be upgrade to Ora11g which has version of  cx_Oracle for 3.4.

Comment: You can't have both version of python running for the same application. You can downgrade your app to run on 2.7 OR you can write a service, running on python 2.7, that wraps your db connection and exposes method through an rpc protocol. But I think it's a pretty bad idea.

Comment: you might look at subprocess: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module.

Comment: Switching from cx_Oracle to pyODBC (http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) is a whole lot easier than upgrading Oracle!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `subprocess` module.

```
def callpython2(file_to_be_executed, params):
    cmd = file_to_be_executed + ' ' + ' '.join(params)
    cmd = %PYTHON2_EXE% + ' ' + cmd

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=cmdEnv, shell=True)
    p.communicate()
```

Afterwards call this function with your file and params, if any. The file's `__main__` function will be called, you can place your function inside the `__main__`

Note: Please check the subprocess [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) for more details on how to capture/control the resulting output or error.

Comment: I'm in a similar boat, and every time I try this (or some variant), I get an error when the secondary script (3.3) tries to load modules from the directory of the primary script (3.4). I've given it the full path to the python executable, but that's not enough. I'm guessing that this is could be handled with the "env" parameter, but I have no idea of which environment variables to set or how to get the proper values. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I think I found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913184/importing-wrong-packages-when-calling-a-python-script-from-another-python-script