# Importing wrong packages when calling a python script from another python script via subprocess

Tags: python, import, subprocess, pydev, cx-freeze

I am trying to automate executable creation for my program in 32 and 64bit with cx_Freeze. I have two separate python 3.4 installations (32 and 64 bit) with all required packages, which all correspond to their appropriate architectures.

However, when I execute the script that calls the different python installations via subprocess, the called python subprocesses import the wrong packages. They **both** import the packages, the original script was called from and **not** the packages the python installation, that was called in the subprocess.

Minimal example called with a 64bit python:

```
#! coding=utf-8
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(["python34-32","test.py"])
sp.call(["python34","test.py"])
```

The test.py contains only the line:

```
import cx_Freeze
```

The second process, that also calls the 64bit python won't have a problem. But the 32bit will throw the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

This is because the subprocess, which is calling 32bit python, imports cx_freeze from the 64bit python. The situation can also be reversed. When the main script is executed with a 32bit python, the same error occurs, however, now it is because the 64bit python called in the suprocess is importing the 32bit freeze package.

How can I stop this behavior and tell it to import from the appropriate source?

I am using Windows 7 x64 and PyDev as IDE, in case it is relevant, which it probably is.

**EDIT:** So apparently it works when the Main Script is executed from command line inside the source directory. Thanks to the comments below, I guess the problem has to with how PyDev sets the environment variables.

Comment: May it be an environmental problem? subprocesses inherit the current environment so, maybe, the new interpreter is looking at the wrong `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: By the way, are you aware of the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) of using `shell=True`? If you aren't using any shell-specific feature you should *not* specify `shell=True` and simply do: `sp.call(['python34-32', 'test.py'])`. If you don't like to write the command as a list you can use `shlex.split`: `import shlex; sp.call(shlex.split('python34-32 test.py'))`.

Comment: What happens if you run `python34-32 test.py` from the command-line in the same directory?

Comment: @Bakuriu: `shlex.split()` uses `sh` syntax that is not very useful on Windows.

Comment: unless you are calling internal command, you could omit `shell=True` on Windows. For portability, you could also specify the command as a list. It shouldn't change the result.

Comment: @bakuriu I am aware of that, however in my case it is perfectly safe, but in principle you are right. I changed the original post accordingly.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian from command line it works in both cases, but I don't know why... fascinating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently PyDev sets the environment variable PYTHONPATH and this is the path that **both** subprocesses use to load their packages.

If I execute the following script in a 64 bit python:

```
#! coding=utf-8
import subprocess as sp

sp.call(["python34-32", "test.py"])
```

whereas `test.py` contains the lines:

```
import os
print(os.getenv("PYTHONPATH"))
```

the result shows the standard folders as they are set for the 64bit python installation.

My guess is, I have to change the PYTHONPATH variable before calling the 32bit python. Does anyone know how to do that?

EDIT: Changing the PYTHONPATH variable in the environment of the subprocess did the trick. Executing the following in a 64bit python will work

```
#! coding=utf-8
import subprocess as sp
import os

env = os.environ
env["PYTHONATH"] = "{INSERT FOLDERS TO 32bit PYTHON}"
sp.call(["python34-32", "test.py"], env=env)
```

Thanks  to bakuriu for getting me on the right track.

Comment: Inside a Python script, inspect `sys.path`. `PYTHONPATH` is just a part of it. `call(["python34-32", "test.py"])` should work even if you delete `PYTHONPATH` envvar: `del env["PYTHONPATH"}` before passing to the child process.